# windows border disappeared in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: unity, compiz, window

the window borders disappeared mostly when I start a game or an application and then close it. it seems to be a compiz issue and when I restart compiz it will work again but I also get the following warning:    compiz (decor) - Warn: failed to bind pixmap to texture
any way to solve this its really annoying???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have the same problem. It's indeed a Compiz bug. I don't have the real solution (will probably come with an update of Compiz) but the easiest workaround is to launch again the compiz window decorator.

Juste type ALT+F2 and enter :

```
/usr/bin/compiz-decorator
```

Comment: thx for the info